# Remove a directory from a URL with regex

Tags: regex, url, url-rewriting

I have a site with the following URL structure in places:

```
www.sitename.com/folder/sub_folder/item
```

What I need to do is remove the `sub_folder` part so that it displays as:

```
www.sitename.com/folder/item
```

Is there a regex expression for that?

Comment: which server are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there's a regex expression, but you should be able to parse, try splitting on '/', then removing everything between the first and last instance, then recombine with '/'

So if string s="www.sitename.com/folder/sub_folder/item";
string newUrl=s.split('/')[0]+"/"+s.split('/')[s.split('/').length];

or something along those lines

Answer (score 0):

In Python, you could do:

```
str1 = "www.sitename.com/folder/sub_folder/item"

str2 = re.sub(r'/\w*(/\w*)$',r'\1',str1)
```